# Cannot add jdk11 and jdk13 in SDK in IntelliJ - java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-11, java-13

I cannot add jdk11 and jdk13 in intelliJ as SDK. I am able to add jdk-18.0_22 only.

Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: What operating system (and version) are you on?

Comment: Win 10, 64 bit OS

Comment: Also, what version of IntelliJ IDEA? IntelliJ seems to accept only Java releases that existed at the time of release.

Comment: intellij 14.1.4, i have the same doubt

Comment: you can get the newest IntelliJ IDEA community edition for free at: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ to gain java 11+ support

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment from @MarsAtomic, I would guess that your version of Intellij (14.1.4) is too old to use the new versions of java.

[14.1.*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html) was last released on May 11, 2016.

[JDK 11 reached General Availability on 25 September 2018](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/).

Comment: The biggest obstacle in recognizing newer JDKs, is the switch to the module system introduced in JDK 9, which is supported since IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3, but substantially improved with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1. So it’s indeed reasonable to assume that any older IntelliJ IDEA version will have problems with any version newer than JDK 9.

Answer (score 4):

The implication of [Java 11 in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/java-11-in-intellij-idea-2018-2/) is that you need to use Intellij IDEA 2018.2 or later to work with Java 11.

I expect that *one* reason that your older Intellij install is not recognizing your Java 11 or Java 13 install is that the JDK classes are packaged differently starting with Java 9.

For support of Java 13 preview features you will need [IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/07/support-for-java-13-preview-features-in-intellij-idea-2019-2/)

Comment: Indeed, the first version with official module support is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.