# Adding the latest JRE version in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

While I was trying out the junit test methods in Java. I've encountered an error that says "release version 13 not supported", so I updated my java to 13 and made it sure that my JDK, JRE version are all updated to java 13 through the terminal. However, the same error still showed up and so I went into the Edit configuration section, but the JRE 13 is not showing up for some reasons. Is there any way to add the JRE 13 in the "add configuration" section? Thank you.

Comment: Is your IntelliJ up-to-date? Also, there's no JRE after 9, only JDK...

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661522